# How to convert bytearray with non-ASCII bytes to string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know how to convert Python's bitarray to string if it contains non-ASCII bytes. Example:

```
>>> string='\x9f'
>>> array=bytearray(string)
>>> array
bytearray(b'\x9f')
>>> array.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In my example, I just want to somehow get a string '\x9f' back from the bytearray. Is that possible?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2. I will add it in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python 2, just pass it to `str()`:

```
>>> import sys; sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> string='\x9f'
>>> array=bytearray(string)
>>> array
bytearray(b'\x9f')
>>> str(array)
'\x9f'
```

In Python 3, you'd want to convert it back to a `bytes` object:

```
>>> bytes(array)
b'\x9f'
```

Comment: Oh. That was it. Simple. (I'm still new in python!)

Answer (score 8):

Did you try

```
byteVariable.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to mention the `binascii` library that comes with Python.

My use case: I was querying a database that had a binary field being used as a key within the DB.  I wanted to pull that binary field and treat it as a key elsewhere. I thought converting it to a string was the best use-case.

binascii offered me a better alternative:

`import binascii
binary_field = bytearray(b'\x92...')
binascii.hexlify(binary_field)`

Comment: The `binascii` module is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

use `bytes(array, encoding='utf8')`