# Scapy spoofing UDP packet error

Tags: python

```
AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute '__rdiv__'
```

I get this for the following code:

```
b = bytearray([0xff, 0xff])

def spoof(src_ip, src_port, dest_ip, dest_port):
    global b
    spoofed_packet = IP(src=src_ip, dst=dest_ip) / TCP(sport=src_port, dport=dest_port) / b
    send(spoofed_packet)
```

Found the example to spoof the packet on stackoverflow but it didn't use a bytearray, I assume I need to convert the bytearray to a string?

Also my scapy keeps opening powershell any way around that?

I fixed that error by making the bytearray into a string now I get the following error:

```
    os.write(1,b".")
    OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: I have updated my answer after the question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Bytearray objects cannot be converted to Packet objects (and thus, Scapy cannot send them, this explains the `'bytearray' object has no attribute '__rdiv__'` error). You need to convert `b`, using `str()` (if you are using Scapy before 2.4.0, with Python 2), or `raw()` (with Scapy 2.4.0 and more, with either Python 2 or 3).

**I strongly recommend that you upgrade to Scapy 2.4.0. This should fix the `Bad file descriptor` error and the Powershell windows.**

For example, your code with `raw()` (replace with `str()` if you are using Scapy < 2.4.0):

```
b = bytearray([0xff, 0xff])

def spoof(src_ip, src_port, dest_ip, dest_port):
    global b
    spoofed_packet = IP(src=src_ip, dst=dest_ip) / TCP(sport=src_port, dport=dest_port) / raw(b)
    send(spoofed_packet)
```

If you don't **have** to use a bytearray object, you can also use a `bytes`/`str` object directly:

```
b = b"\xff\xff"

def spoof(src_ip, src_port, dest_ip, dest_port):
    global b
    spoofed_packet = IP(src=src_ip, dst=dest_ip) / TCP(sport=src_port, dport=dest_port) / b
    send(spoofed_packet)
```

Comment: I think this is more of a installation issue rather than a coding issue now

Comment: Of course, if then question changes... Anyway, you **have** to convert bytearray objects to send them, and I **think** the bug would be fixed by upgrading...

Answer (score 0):

Could perhaps be with the version of Python that you are using?

Looks like the `__rdiv__` operator may have been depreciated in python3?

See the following SO question:

[Have the `__rdiv__()` and `__idiv__` operators changed in Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344025/have-the-rdiv-and-idiv-operators-changed-in-python-3-x)

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
from scapy.all import IP, UDP, L3RawSocket, conf
from scapy.all import send as scapy_send


def send(dest_ip, port, src_ip, payload, count=1):
    if dest_ip in ("127.0.0.1", "localhost"):
        conf.L3socket = L3RawSocket
    ip = IP(dst=dest_ip, src=src_ip)
    udp = UDP(dport=port)
    scapy_send(ip/udp/str(payload), count=count)


send("192.168.1.100", 9090, "192.168.33.100", "Tarun here", 2)
```

[image: UDP Packet sending]

Comment: For `bytearray` look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657570/how-to-convert-bytearray-with-non-ascii-bytes-to-string-in-python

Comment: I still get os.write(1,b".")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor with that function :/

Comment: Which OS is it?

Comment: Windows 10, it gives the same error on the original function

Comment: Can you make sure the setup is fine? Use steps listed in this https://github.com/zlorb/scapy and also make sure you run your program with admin rights

Comment: WARNING: PyX dependencies are not installed ! Please install TexLive or MikTeX.
WARNING: Winpcap is installed over Npcap. Will use Winpcap (see 'Winpcap/Npcap conflicts' in scapy's docs)

from running scapy.bat, I can't pip install texlive or miktex

Comment: So you have `Npcap` installed? and not `Winpcap`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168486/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-ayy).