# How to convert bytearray to string in python

Tags: python

I need to convert the next bytearray to string:

```
Num = bytearray()
```

I have tried

```
Num = bytearray(str)
```

but that's not the solution

Comment: [`bytearray.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.decode)

Comment: You can try below link. I hope it help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657570/how-to-convert-bytearray-with-non-ascii-bytes-to-string-in-python

Comment: I checked it and yeah it helped me, I've solved that problem, thank you

Answer (score 28):

As [t.m.adam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094765/how-to-convert-bytearray-to-string-in-python/50094913#comment87205717_50094765) said in the comments, use [`bytearray.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.decode)

```
b = bytearray("test", encoding="utf-8")
b.decode()
#> 'test'
```

Comment: Running `b.decode()` with no consideration of the original bytearray's encoding (or whether it even represents encoded Unicode text) is just going to lead to UnicodeDecodeErrors and encoding bugs.