# How to convert bitarray data to string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, binary, bitarray

I have binary code in bitarray. I want to display the contents of the bitarray, as a string. How can I fix the code to display the content.

```
from bitarray import bitarray
data = bitarray('010101')
print(str(data))
```

My output:

```
bitarray('010101')
```

I need:

```
010101
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert bytearray to string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094765/how-to-convert-bytearray-to-string-in-python)

Comment: @AnuragDabas No, this is about "bytearray". I have problem with "bitarray".

Comment: @stfxc, could you please upvote/validate if any of the answers helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
print(data.to01())
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides method `.to01`, you can also use `decodetree` which will allow you to specify what you want to use instead of 0 and instead of 1:

```
>> from bitarray import bitarray, decodetree
>> t = decodetree({'0': bitarray('0'), '1': bitarray('1')})
>> data = bitarray('010101')
>>> ''.join(data.decode(t))
010101
```

For more info about `.to01`, `decode` and other methods/functions, see the docs for `bitarray` [here](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray).